# How to search for documents created by a specific user across multiple site collections?

Tags: search

I have a requirement to display a list of the 10 most recently created documents by the current user across multiple site collections. I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I have tried using the Author managed property but this just contains the display name of the user, so if there are two users with the same name they may potentially see each others documents.  Is there a managed property that contains the username of the author of a document?  I know there is a 'Document Created By' field on libraries that contains the username but as this field is hidden it does not get indexed by search.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried creating a Query Rule for this (or even a Result Source)? I demonstrate both in my SPC14 Session (http://bit.ly/abSPC322).

Use the query `{subjectTerms} Author:{User.Name} IsDocument=1`

SharePoint will handle the User Name substitution for you.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I've not tried a Query Rule or Result Source but I think that I may run into the same problem in that the Author managed property only contains the display name of the user and not their username.

Comment: I do think it's worth a try. Let me know what happens and report back. I'll set up a test on my environment in the next day or two.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cannot do it but I had the same problem years ago and I did it an event receiver in order to fill a new string field with the username. Then you could create a new mapped property based on that new field (added previously to content type) and get the author. Make sense? :)